# adding a 'test' fs to an LVM group

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, lvm, acl

I'm trying to follow [this](https://blogging.dragon.org.uk/samba4-ad-dc-on-ubuntu-14-04/) guide to get a Samba DC going.

However, I can't seem to get past the step for adding a 'test' volume to test the ACLs on.

My fstab is as follows:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/DCserver--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0      $
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=1fdd6894-b065-4304-aa56-d26a01526046 /boot           ext2    defaults     $
/dev/mapper/DCserver--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0      $
```

I think I need to actually create something using some commands on the command line, but I have no idea how to proceed.

I tried adding the attributes for using ACLs to the options of root FS in fstab, but it failed and I had to reinstall/start over

Is it possible to add a fake/test volume to a test fs, so that I can test the correct workings of ACLs without touching the root filesystem?

Comment: Are you sure the problem simply is not you should not be using root `/` and something like `/data` instead?  Look back over that link and ensure you read it correctly for what you are typing in the `/etc/fstab` file.

Comment: Thanks. I got the test setup working by copying the vg to a new line, calling it /data and adding the required options. I got it as a new filesystem under /data. So I guess that you did answer the question in a way. Unfortunately, I still have to learn how to use lvm properly, as I haven't been able to get anything else to work.

Comment: I'm still learning Linux myself man... what are you having trouble with and what is the error message, etc.? Do you want me to add something I mentioned in a comment as an answer or you want to get more help with issues? I'm happy to do whatever but give me some detail on your issue but if it's different it may be better for another question but I'll listen to what's up regardless just in case. Let me know about this issue being resolved for the question you asked and what you reported and if you think I should add an answer or whatever too.